# FFMPEG upload output to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have a video file stored in my S3 bucket. I want to take that file as the input, do some processing with FFMPEG and directly upload it to S3. How can I do this?

Comment: Using aws-cli and shell script will work.

Comment: @shimo but how? can you show an example?

Comment: [get-object](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html), process FFMPEG, [put-objetct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html). Please try yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it yourself, or use [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html).

If you wish to **use FFMPEG yourself**, you will need somewhere to run it. This could be on an Amazon EC2 instance, or on your own computer. Your program or script would need to download the video from the S3 bucket, process it with FFMPEG and then upload the resulting file to S3.

Or, you could use **Amazon Elastic Transcoder** to transcode the file. It is not FFMPEG, but it has many of the same capabilities. It can read the video directly from S3 and output the result to S3. Pricing is based on the length of the input video file (eg 3c per minute).

Actually, a newer product called [AWS Elemental MediaConvert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/what-is.html) is also an option. It is a professional video system used by the broadcasting industry, so it has a lot more options.